# Consuming Azure Devops python library from Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, azure-devops, jupyter-notebook

I have a custom python library that's published as Azure Devops feed. I am able to access it to deploy to other servers using the endpoint from the release pipeline. I am trying to access/install the library in a Jupyter notebook locally for testing purposes.

From the Azure Devops documentation -
`Ensure you have installed the latest version of the Azure Artifacts keyring from the "Get the tools" menu. Add a pip.ini (Windows) or pip.conf (Mac/Linux) file to your virtualenv and pip install.`

I have setup the Key Ring and my pip.ini is pointing to the ‘https://xxx@pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxxx/zzzz0acc9/_packaging/MyFeed/pypi/simple/. When I try to call the pip install 'libraryname' according to the documenation, I am getting the message - ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement. I have included the Personal Access Token after the https which has the necessary rights but with no luck.

The goal I am trying to achieve is use the library in a Jupyter notebook locally but I am not sure whether these are all the steps needed. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the pip.ini file is placed in the correct location. You can run `pip config -v list` command to check the locations of the configuration files that pip tries to load from.

You have to make sure your pip.ini is in one of the locations listed by above `pip config -v list command`

You can also try running `pip install`  on your local machine commandline terminal to install your private package.

See below my test:

```
#pip.ini 

[global]
extra-index-url=https://PersonalAccessToken@pkgs.dev.azure.com/MyOrg/_packaging/MyPythonFeed/pypi/simple/
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much @Levi Lu-MSFT, My ini was under the project and I had to move to the venv location. I am able to install the library locally now :)